# The problem of return reference to local variable

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Returning reference to a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499864/returning-reference-to-a-local-variable)

I happened to find this code return 5. It's OK to write it this way or should definitely be avoid?

```
   int& f() {

     int i = 5; 
     return i;
}

int main(){

    cout<<f()<<endl;    
}
```

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755010/best-way-to-return-early-from-a-function-returning-a-reference and related to *this posters* earlier questions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474852/what-issue-is-related-with-function-that-return-a-reference-c-closed .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it works, it works only by accident. This is undefined behavior and should definitely be avoided.

The moment that f returns, there are no longer any guarantees as to what happens to the memory where `i` lived and what happens when you try to access it.

Comment: Agreed. +1. You might also want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755010/

Answer (score 4):

The compiler warning is correct — you can't do that. `i` is likely to be overwritten at some unexpected time.

Either do

```
int f() { // don't return reference

     int i = 5; 
     return i;
}

int main(){

    cout<<f()<<endl;    
}
```

or

```
int &f( int &i ) { // accept reference
  // actually, in the case of modify-and-return like this,
  // you should call by value and return by value without
  // using any references. This is for illustration.

     i = 5; 
     return i;
}

int main(){
    int i
    cout<<f(i)<<endl;    
}
```

Comment: If you're modifying a by-reference parameter in place, returning the reference as well seems strange (second example). I'm not saying it's wrong, of course.

Comment: @Steve: Sometimes it's the thing to do. Given the example, it would appear that he wants a reference and a return value. *shrug* In the particular case of an `int`, using references is basically incorrect.

Comment: @Steve: It's exactly what happens when you overload `operator<<` for your own types. You take an `ostream&` and return the same `ostream&`.

Comment: @FredOverflow - and just look at how many people really hate the stream operators. I'm not one of them, by the way, but you have to admit - they are definitely a special case in more than one way. For example, they also give a completely new meaning to old operators - not something to recommend as an everyday practice.

Answer (score 2):

When the function 'f()' returns, the stack contents will be popped, and the memory address to the variable 'i' will no longer be valid. This code should not be used.