# Why can't a reference to a temporary object be returned

Tags: c++

test1 is correct(compiling with g++), but test2 is error. Why?

```cpp
int& test1(){
    int a = 10;
    int& res = a;
    return res;
}
int& test2(){
    int a = 10;
    return a;
}
```

Comment: [Both are not good.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/86twjI5yKAxkemwO)

Comment: Both are invalid, you return a reference to object that is dead.

Comment: you can but you shall not.

Comment: local variables cease to exist once the function returns, you can return the reference but it is completely useless outside of the function

Comment: Coz variable a is local and you can't access it in the function. But if you declare it as global you can access it inside.

Comment: [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rawZ46r42JjCgWF3) is a reason you shouldn't do `test1`. [Here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1F1PGFM2tCFSpTl8) is a reason you shouldn't do `test2`. Both codes cause undefined behavior. Anything can happen. The first exampe returns unexpected values and the second example crashes. It's probably even possible to make `test1` crash, too.

Comment: _"Why?"_ Because: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7499864/returning-reference-to-a-local-variable

Comment: it is correct when compiling test1 with gcc

Comment: @xinger Compilers can't catch every variation of every error that exists... your first example makes it harder to catch because of the intermediate assignment, but returning a reference or pointer to a local is a very bad idea no matter how you do it.

Comment: see here for an example where `test1()` fails miserably: https://godbolt.org/z/nGa96eYnc Look at the output, then turn on compiler optimizations via -O2, look at the output again. Thats one typical consequence of undefined behavior. Only with optimizations turned on the compiler cares to optimize away code thats not doing any good anyhow

Comment: interestingly gcc only issues a warning when optimizations are turned on.

Comment: Voting to reopen because many people will fail to find the duplicate question - the question titles are expressed in very different ways.