# what should I return if I don't have something to return for an unknown type

Tags: c++, methods, return, option-type, typename

For the following code, what should I return if I don't have something to return ? Currently, I do something like T() but I'm not sure it's correct and proper.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
tuple<T1, T2, bool> CBR<T1, T2>::getSomething(T1 t)
{
    // here I I don't have something of time T2 or T2 to return
    if( ... )
        return make_tuple(T1(), T2(), false); // @FIXME

    if( ... )
        return make_tuple(something.tp, something.ts, false);
    else
        return make_tuple(something.tp, something.ts, true);
}
```

Comment: That's a [design question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1755380/140719). What's the function _supposed_ to return if it cannot return something?

Comment: Are you aware of `boost::optional`?

Comment: BTW, the last 4 lines should just be `return make_tuple(something.tp, something.ts, !(...));`

Comment: @FredOverflow using boost::optional even if T1 and T2 are not needed, I want to return false, so that the user who call this will know that he should not cout T1 and T2 for example (because there is no T1 and T2 actually). Is it possible ?

Comment: So when the boolean is false, there is no real T1 and T2 part? It sounds like you want a `boost::optional<pair<T1, T2> >` then.

Comment: @FredOverflow How is it possible to test that the method returned something or didn't returned anything ? We should use something like: if( obj.getSomething(t) != boost::none ) tie(var1, va2, var3) = obj.getSomething(t); ?

Comment: You can simply say `if (obj.getSomething(t)) { ... }`, no need for an explicit comparison.

Comment: @FredOverflow In this case we should call getSomething twice ?! Because we don't know if there is a tuple to get or not, then we need to do `if(obj.getSomething(t)) { tie(var1, va2, var3) = obj.getSomething(t); }` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
boost::optional<tuple<T1, T2, bool> >
```

The "good" return paths will be unchanged; the "FIXME" one will become:

```
return boost::none;
```

This can allow your class to be used with types that do not support default construction.

Comment: For the FIXME part of code, T1 and T2 are not needed but I want to return false, so that the user who call this will know that he should not cout T1 and T2 for example (because there is no T1 and T2 actually).

Comment: How is it possible to test that the method returned something or didn't returned anything ? We should use something like: if( obj.getSomething(t) != boost::none ) tie(var1, va2, var3) = obj.getSomething(t);

Comment: `if (boost::optional<tuple<...> > result = obj.getSomething(t)) tie(var1, var2, var3) = *result;`